# Problema al guardar un archivo en una carpeta, que viene de tipo byte[] en el servidor al usar WriteAllBytes en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, archivo

tengo la siguiente funcion.

```
 private void guardarimagen( byte[] img)
 {
                var path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/prueba.jpg");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, img);
  }
```

EN localhost funciona bien, pero cuando lo pruebo en producción, me dice error:
**[object Object]**

Me imagino que tiene que ver con tema de permisos, pero debe haber otra forma de implementar mediante codigo para que funcione.

Si alguien  tiene alguna idea, se lo agradecería bastante.

Comment: Debes autenticar para poder escribir en el servidor, es lo que asumo por lo que veo de tu código. [Aquí puedes revisar de que hablo](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/306158/how-to-implement-impersonation-in-an-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 1):

Tengo esta funcion.. pero trabaja con un base64. para convertir de arreglo de bit a base64 solo tienes que hacer esto :

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(direccion);
string image = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);





//dale un base64 de una imagen y te la convertira a un archivo fisico
//si el directorio que le pasaste no existe.. lo creara
public static string ToImage(string base64coded, string sName, string sRuta)
{
    try
    {
        string folderRoute = sRuta;
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderRoute))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderRoute);
        }
        string imageName = sName + ".jpg";
        if (base64coded.IndexOf("data:image/jpeg;base64,") == 0)
        {
            base64coded = base64coded.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
        }
        var bytesss = Convert.FromBase64String(base64coded);
        string Route = folderRoute + "\\" + imageName;
        using (var imageFile = new FileStream(Route, FileMode.Create))
        {
            imageFile.Write(bytesss, 0, bytesss.Length);
            imageFile.Flush();
        }

        return Route;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: pero es un binario que necesito transformar en archivo y guardarlo

Comment: Actualice la respuesta. espero te sirva.

Comment: gracias por responder, pero aun me sale el mismo error en producción con tu ejemplo. Deduzco que debe ser algun problema de permisos al usar el write. El error es  [object Object], es sale en el mensaje de alerta